# Can't cast an instant after my opponent declares attackers in Arena

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-arena

If I have an instant that gives a creature +1/+7 ([Aegis of the Heavens](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAegis%20of%20the%20Heavens%5d)) until end of turn, I should be able to cast this after my opponent declares their attackers, right? Because the game hasn't been giving me the opportunity.

Comment: Are you sure that you had enough untapped lands in the right colors to cast the spell at that time? Arena will skip opportunities to cast spells like that if you are not actually capable of casting anything.

Comment: @murgatroid99 That is not universally true. There are bugs in the autotap algorithms that make the game skip opportunities that you actually have. Example from reddit, submitted by me: https://www.reddit.com/r/MagicArena/comments/9abyhg/ai_does_not_understand_unclaimed_territory/

Comment: Sometimes switching to full-control mode is necessary, have you had it enabled?

Comment: @Marcus I did not, but that's besides the point, the behaviour was clearly a bug in an important feature. Full control would have been one workaround, as would have been manually tapping before casting, but you can't reasonably expect such behaviour, so there was no reason use those workarounds before you knew about the issue.

Comment: @ TeaNTea Welcome to the site! In the future it may be helpful to take a screenshot of the board state so answers have more information to figure out what might have happened. In arena you should have had two opportunities to cast your pump spell (after declare attacks, and after declare blocks) without having to go to full control.

Comment: @Hackworth I never claimed that being unable to cast the spell was the only possible explanation. But it is one possible explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, declaring attackers happens during the Declare Attackers step ([rule 508](http://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020181005.txt)). After declaring attackers (508.1), the active player (your opponent) gets priority (508.2) but you'll get priority thereafter and should be able to cast an instant.

Unless there are other effects in place barring you from casting spells, it seems to be an Arena bug.